# android how to hide a edittext and reclaim the space

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a UI that has a handful of text entries that might be needed by the user.  The users selects the type of entry from a spinner.  when the selection is made I change the visibility of some edittext controls and change the label that goes with it.

The problem is the space where the edittext was is now blank and the screen layout looks screwy.

I put all of this in a table, hoping I could hide a row, but that didnt help either.

Any ideas short of make a new class for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the visibility to `View.HIDDEN`, set it to `View.GONE`. From the [description for View.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE):

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't
>   take any space for layout purposes.
>   Use with [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

just make sure u use [SetVisibility(View.GONE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)